# if statement is not utilizing values in the array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

This code is supposed to:

1. Create an array with a *Scanner input* and use *String.split*
2. Calculate the GPA and determine whether the student is eligible for sports based on the GPA and the number of classes taken.

As is, the code runs correctly but it does not use the *Scanner input* or *String.split* like it is supposed to.

The code at the top that is commented out was what I had been working on to use *String.split*, but when I do that, the if statement that calculates the GPA does not work. There are no error messages, the GPA just returns as 0.0.

Can someone tell me what the issue is or point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //Initialize array  
    double GPA = 0;
    boolean hasF = false;
        

    /*String str = "a,b";
    String[] arr = str.split(",");*/
    

        String [] arr = new String [] {"a", "a", "b", "a", "c"};  //change the grades accordingly
        double len = arr.length;
        System.out.println("Elements of given array: ");  
        //Loop through the array by incrementing value of i  
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {  
            System.out.println(arr[i] + " "); 
        }
        for (String i : arr) {//goes through each value and adds to GPA accordingly
          if (i == "a") {
            GPA = GPA + 4.0;
            
          }
          else if (i == "b") {
            GPA = GPA + 3.0;
            
          }
          else if (i == "c") {
            GPA = GPA + 2.0;
            
          }
          else if (i == "d") {
            GPA = GPA + 1.0;
             
          }
          else if (i == "f"){
            GPA = GPA + 0.0;
            hasF = true;
          } 
          else {//invalid input?
            System.out.println("invalid input: " + i);
            return;
          }
        }
        
        GPA = GPA/len;//calculate GPA
        System.out.println("GPA: " + GPA);

        
        if (len < 4) {//determines elegebility
          System.out.println("You are ineligable to participate in activities and sport because you are not taking enough classes.");
        }
        else if (hasF == true && GPA >= 2.0){
          System.out.println("You are ineligable to participate in activities and sports because you have an F. Even though your GPA is greater than 2.0 and you are taking enough classes.");
        }
        else if (hasF == true && GPA <= 2.0) {
          System.out.println("You are ineligable to participate in activities and sports because you have an F and your GPA is less than a 2.0.");
        }
        else if (hasF == false && GPA <= 2.0){
          System.out.println("You are ineligable to participate in activities and sports because your GPA is less than a 2.0.");
        }

        else if (hasF == true){
          System.out.println("You are ineligable to participate in activities and sports because you have an F.");
        }
        else{
          System.out.println("You are Eligable to participate in activities and sports. GOOD JOB!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

*I already turned the assignment in so you're not helping me cheat

Comment: String comparison would not work correctly with `==` in java, can you try and use `i.equals("a")` instead? or `i.equalsIgnoreCase("a")`

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest to use `switch` `case` in this scenario, it would lead to a much cleaner code.

Comment: i run your code it works well,The GPA is  3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in your if condition is: you are trying to compare `String` values using `==` but this will check for reference of `String` values because `String` is an object and `==` (2 equal sign) checks for their references which are the same or not.
to compare `String` values you need to call `equals()` methods of `String` as : `"a".equals(i)` or `i.equals("a")`. the `"a".equals(i)` comparison is better because it will prevent from `NullPointerException`:

```
if ("a".equals(i)) {
    GPA = GPA + 4.0;
    
} else if ("b".equals(i)) {
    GPA = GPA + 3.0;

} else if ("c".equals(i)) {
    GPA = GPA + 2.0;

} else if ("d".equals(i)) {
    GPA = GPA + 1.0;

} else if ("f".equals(i)) {
    GPA = GPA + 0.0;
    hasF = true;
} else {// invalid input?
    System.out.println("invalid input: " + i);
    return;
}
```

to complete the code:

1. to get the commat separated (,) values from user to you need to define a `Scanner` object and prompt the user to enter the **grade** values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Initialize array
    double GPA = 0;
    boolean hasF = false;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("please enter the grades and seperate by (,): ");
    String str = input.nextLine();
    String[] arr = str.split(",");

//      String[] arr = new String[] { "a", "a", "b", "a", "c" }; // change the grades accordingly
    double len = arr.length;
    System.out.print("Elements of given array: ");
    // Loop through the array by incrementing value of i
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (String i : arr) {// goes through each value and adds to GPA accordingly
        if ("a".equals(i)) {
            GPA = GPA + 4.0;

        } else if ("b".equals(i)) {
            GPA = GPA + 3.0;

        } else if ("c".equals(i)) {
            GPA = GPA + 2.0;

        } else if ("d".equals(i)) {
            GPA = GPA + 1.0;

        } else if ("f".equals(i)) {
            GPA = GPA + 0.0;
            hasF = true;
        } else {// invalid input?
            System.out.println("invalid input: " + i);
            return;
        }
    }

    GPA = GPA / len;// calculate GPA
    System.out.println("GPA: " + GPA);

    if (len < 4) {// determines elegebility
        System.out.println(
                "You are ineligable to participate in activities and sport because you are not taking enough classes.");
    } else if (hasF == true && GPA >= 2.0) {
        System.out.println(
                "You are ineligable to participate in activities and sports because you have an F. Even though your GPA is greater than 2.0 and you are taking enough classes.");
    } else if (hasF == true && GPA <= 2.0) {
        System.out.println(
                "You are ineligable to participate in activities and sports because you have an F and your GPA is less than a 2.0.");
    } else if (hasF == false && GPA <= 2.0) {
        System.out.println(
                "You are ineligable to participate in activities and sports because your GPA is less than a 2.0.");
    }

    else if (hasF == true) {
        System.out.println("You are ineligable to participate in activities and sports because you have an F.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You are Eligable to participate in activities and sports. GOOD JOB!!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you are importing the Scanner object, you must also create a Scanner object. I would recommend putting `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` at the top of your main method. Then you can read in the input using `String foo = input.nextLine();`. It also might make sense to prompt the user for input with something like `System.out.print("Enter grades separated by commas with no spaces: ")`. To split it, do `foo.split(',');`.

Another piece of advice, hasF is a boolean so it has a value of `true` or `false`. This means comparing hasF to `true` or `false` is redundant. You can shorten your if statements to `if (hasF && GPA >= 2.0)` if you're comparing hasF to true and `if (!hasF && GPA >= 2.0)` if you're comparing hasF to false.